# How to combine column header names in excel,before loading it into a target table using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, excel, ssis, vba

There is an excel sheet(this screen shot  is only a part ,which shows first 5 columns from a wider 800 column sheet!) with below mentioned format.

[image]
The column names are in the 4th row .I need to make column names as a combination of 3rd and 
4th columns,before loading it into table using SQL SERVER INTEGRATION SERVICE(SSIS).How to import the file to meet the requirements>?

example of column names required in the target table:-

```
[Plcn Pyll SUM 00BASELINE]  

[Plcn Pyll SUM 04QUARTER_2014_15_Q1]

[Plcn Pyll SUM 08QUARTER_2014_15_Q2]
```

How to import the excel file to meet the requirement?

(SSIS Flat file connection manager has some limitations right? So this has to be handled in excel vb level?)

If I convert excel to txt and try to import using flat file connection manager,It shows
 "`there is more than one data source column with same name`" .

The thing is `00BASELINE` is appeared more than one time among the 800 column headers..

Comment: FYI, anybody who doesn't know what "SSIS" means will be unlikely to help you.

Comment: That might be true..we can use vb.net inside ssis. Also a soution can be a combination of excel- vba and ssis

Comment: Looking at this again, I suggest you combine the names using a VBA macro before importing with SSIS.